# Selected activity page keeps jumping back to main activity page. How do I stop this from happening?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a six-level memory match game with a spinner to select levels. When I select a level, it goes to that screen for a split second, then back to the main activity screen every time. How do I set it up to stay on the chosen screen?

Here's the Main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:entries="@array/menu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="This is Daytona!"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    int currentItem = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                //String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent intent;

                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        return;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Charlotte.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bristol.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Here's the Charlotte.java

```
public class Charlotte extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    int currentItem = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_charlotte);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                //String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent intent;

                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(Charlotte.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        return;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(Charlotte.this, Bristol.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

And the third page Bristol.java

```
public class Bristol extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    int currentItem = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bristol);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                //String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent intent;

                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(Bristol.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(Bristol.this, Charlotte.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: What option are you selecting in what activity?

Comment: Oops! The Main.xml is the same for all three xml pages. Daytona is the main page and the menu options are (from the strings.xml file):                                                   <array name="menu">
        <item>Daytona Driver/Driver</item>
        <item>Charlotte Driver/Driver</item>
        <item>Bristol Driver/Driver</item>
    </array>

Comment: Remove tools:context=".MainActivity"

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I tried a few different things with it, including taking the tolls:context out of each xml page, but it didn't fix it. i should clarify here (since I didn't think of it earlier) that the main activity page has ".MainActivity", the second page has ".Charlotte", and the third page has ".Bristol". I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried a similar experiment with buttons and it worked beautifully. Maybe the spinner has a different set of rules?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tools:context=".MainActivity"` as it restricts context to one activity